# Time Dimension Using Multiple Columns

Tags: time, ssas

In my relational table, I have dates in columns dt_X and dt_Q and a boolean flag.

For my time dimension in my SSAS cube, I want it to use dt_X if the boolean flag is true; otherwise use dt_Q.

How can I can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your Data Source View for Time Dimension, add a Named Calculation like:

```
CASE Flag 
    WHEN 1 
        THEN dt_X
    ELSE dt_Q
END
```

And use this as the source column for the required attribute.